# JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I am new to Java EE and am using JBoss 7 to create my first project. I have an EAR project, an EJB project, WEB project and a JPA project in my workspace. The ejb created in the EJB project wants to use an ejb created in the JPA project. It all compiles fine, however when I deploy the EAR project I get the following exception and the deployement fails. Here is the main exception cause.

> JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type
>   'com.kohlisoft.stockmanagement.jpa.service.StockManagementBeanJpa' for
>   binding
>   com.kohlisoft.stockmanagement.ejb.main.StockManagementService/sms

I suspect that the EJB project is not able to look at the class in jpa jar.

I have gone though various links to sort it out but no help. Based on few suggestions I have modified it but still no joy.
1. I checked the structure and the JPA project is going under the lib folder in .ear.
2. Updated the EJB project's manifest file to add the dependeny to the jpa jar.

I would really appreciate any help here.

The EJB in the JPA project.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StockManagementBeanJpaBean implements StockManagementBeanJpa {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="StockManagement")
    private EntityManager em;
```

The EJB in the EJB project which uses it:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StockManagementService implements StockManagementServiceLocal {

    @EJB
    StockManagementBeanJpa sms;

...
```

EJB Project MANIFEST file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: StockManagement-ejbClient.jar
Dependencies: lib/StockManagement-jpa.jar
```

Here is the structure of the .jars and .war in .ear.

```
.ear
 |____ ejb.jar
 |
 |____ ejbClient.jar
 |
 |____ web.war
 |
 |____ /lib
         |
         | ____ jpa.jar
         |
         | ____ all other jars related to derby client, hibernate, jta etc.
```

Let me know if any other files are required.

Comment: I think you're supposed to annotate your interfaces with Remote or Local annotations.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine - the annotations you mentioned are applied on the respective interfaces.

Answer (score 11):

Your file structure looks alright.

So, where is the **problem** ?

`@Localbean` should be used inside your *EJB* bean only when your EJB is not extending interface. `@Local` can be used for *interface* and then extending your *EJB* with the interface or using `@Local` straingh inside your *no-interface EJB*. But `@Localbean` is only used for *no-interface EJB*. So, what you are doing is not right.

Since you are extending interface, do as below:

**Interface**

```
@Local
public interface StockManagementBeanJpa
{

....

}
```

**EJB**

```
@Stateless
public class StockManagementBeanJpaBean implements StockManagementBeanJpa 
{

....

}
```

Do this for all EJBs.

I want to point out 1 more thing that `@Local` will work in your case because you are calling EJBs from the same application (same EAR). This will not work in the case of cross application call(different EAR, WAR ...) or remote client calling your EJB. In this case, you will need `@Remote`.

Comment: the problem is not the proper formation of jars. The problem is that the EBJ jar is not able to see the ejb's under JPA jar. If I move the JPA jar at the same level of EJB jar it works fine. Hope this information helps.

Comment: If Jar visibility is a problem then move it one level up. Does it work with your code ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur time. As already mentioned if i move it a level up it works fine, since day one. But I don't want to change the structure, infact want to access that jar as per the existing structure. I am sure it is possible but the only thing is don't know the correct way to do it.

Comment: Do one thing. After deployment, check if all the EJBs are deployed properly. Check their deployed JNDI names.

Comment: With the existing structure. The ejbs in the jpa.jar are deployed but the ejbs in the EJB.jar are not deployed as it is not able to see the ejbs in jpa.jar, so the deployment fails. This is why when i move the jpa.jar one level up it is able to deploy all the jars.

Comment: I don't think you need dependency. Deploy all EJBs as independents as a part of EAR.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally had these imports in the EJB after some copy-pasting:

```
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
```

The EJB looked like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MyService {
```

Maven build went thru but the class was not deployed as EJB. After removing `import javax.inject.Singleton;` it worked fine.