# WFLYEJB0405: No EJB found with interface of type .... my ejb class name

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

My project is a webapplication which is running on jboss EAP 7 and developed in struts and spring which calling a ejb class which is present in a jar file and that jar file is there in the build path (lib folder of my main project) and i mentioned the class name in web.xml. When i am building  my project its showing below error please help where need to configure and what i need to do. my project is on Jboss EAP 7

Note:- My ejb class is not annotation based.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0405: No EJB found with interface of type 'common.ejb.service.BusinessServiceLocalHome' and name 'BusinessService.jar#BusinessService' for binding java:module/env/local/loan/BusinessService
```

web.xml:-

```
<ejb-local-ref id="EJBLocalRef_1179231224570">
        <ejb-ref-name>local/Loan/BusinessService</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local-home>common.ejb.service.BusinessServiceLocalHome</local-home>
        <local>common.ejb.service.BusinessServiceLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>BusinessService.jar#BusinessService</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Comment: This might help you out [no ejb found with interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755093/jbas014544-no-ejb-found-with-interface), I'd get rid of the `ejb-local-ref` and instead use annotations, JBoss 7 now scans for EJB's

Comment: Are you deploying an EAR file or a WAR file? If it's a WAR file is the BusinessService.jar built into the WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: Hi @JGlass its a old application which in ran previously in tomcat now we are migrating to Jboss EAP 7 , please guide without changing the ejb class annotation based.

Comment: Hi #Steve C ys i am creating a war file and  also BusinessService.jar also available in WEB-INF/lib folder of my main project

Answer (score 1):

Because you're only building a WAR file, you can remove:

```
 <ejb-link>BusinessService.jar#BusinessService</ejb-link>
```

This mechanism is only required in a multi-module EAR file. All jars in a WAR file are considered to be part of the same web module.

Comment: Hi @Steve C  i tried by removing this <ejb-link> still i am getting the same error at the time of project build. i want to say one thing like the same set up  worked fine when i was in tomcat server, when i am using jboss i am getting this error. Is  in jboss server any where we need to mention about this ejb class.

Comment: That is not possible as Tomcat does not support EJBs like this. Also you cannot be getting the same error as the first one refers specifically to `BusinessService.jar#BusinessService`, and you say you have removed the reference

Comment: I'm letting Steve take over as he's way more experienced - thanks for jumping in Steve!